# Lazos de control

Tags: python, bucles

Estoy desarrollando un pequeño programita para establecer el control de posición mediante un PID para un coche.

Estoy partiendo de un movimiento sencillo, simplemente estoy modelando un movimiento rectilíneo uniformemente acelerado sobre el cuál quiero imponer que se llegue hasta una cierta posición s. Para ello, tengo un lazo de control con PID anidado, de forma que la acción de control sea sobre la aceleración del cuerpo.

[image: Lazo de control]

En la Figura de arriba adjunto el bucle de control, donde:

- x_sp define la posición a la que quiero llegar
- e_1 define el error en la posición y que permitirá definir un setpoint de velocidad a alcanzar
- v_sp viene definido como el error en posición por la v maxima alcanzable
- e_2 es el error entre la velocidad que se debería llevar y la que se lleva en t
- u define la señal del control del pid
- x_i es la posición que tengo en t, calcula a partir de la aceleración y velocidad en t

La lógica  a seguir sería: primero, calculo el error en posición, con ello defino un setpoint de velocidad con el que calcular un nuevo error que permitirá ejercer la acción de control.

Finalmente se debería obtener una gráfica en la cuál se alcanze la posición y se quede estable, teniendo, intuyo,  una velocidad 0 y una aceleración 0. Sin embargo, implementando esta lógica no obtengo este tipo de gráfica, si no que mi posición y velocidad siguen creciendo.

Dejo por aquí el código de ayuda:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

init_time = 0.
end_time = 300.
step = 0.1
sim_time = np.arange(init_time, end_time, step)

s_0 = 0.
v_0 = 0.
a_max = 2.5
a_0 = a_max
v_max = 120 * (1000 / 3600)

def position(s_0, v_0, a, t):
    s = s_0 + v_0 * t + 0.5 * a * t**2

return s

def velocity(v_0, a, t):
     v = v_0 + a * t
return v

Kp = 1
Kd = 0
Ki = 0

s_setpoint = 1000

def error(setpoint, actual):
      e = (setpoint - actual) / setpoint
      return e

def control_signal(e, E_e, e_prev, delta_t):
       u = Kp * e + Ki * E_e * delta_t + Kd * (e - e_prev) / delta_t
       return u 

pos = np.zeros([len(sim_time)])
vel = np.zeros([len(sim_time)])
acel = np.zeros([len(sim_time)])
err1 = np.zeros([len(sim_time)])
err2 = np.zeros([len(sim_time)])

e_01 = 0
e_02 = 0

for i in range(len(sim_time)):
    pos[i] = s_0
    vel[i] = v_0
    acel[i] = a_0
    e_t1 = error(s_setpoint, s_0)
    err1[i] = e_t1


    v_sp = v_max * e_t1
    e_t2 = error(v_sp, v_0)
    sum_e2 = e_t2 + e_02
    e_02 = sum_e2
    err2[i] = e_t2

    u_t2 = control_signal(e_t2, sum_e2, err2[-1], step)
    a_0 = a_max * u_t2

    if a_0 > a_max:
         a_0 = a_max
    elif a_0 < -a_max:
         a_0 = -a_max

    v_0 = velocity(v_0, a_0, step)
    s_0 = position(s_0, v_0, a_0, step)

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(1, 3, 1)
plt.scatter(sim_time, pos)
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('Time [secs]')
plt.ylabel('Position [m]')

plt.subplot(1, 3, 2)
plt.scatter(sim_time, vel * 3600 / 1000)
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('Time [secs]')
plt.ylabel('Velocity [kmh]')

plt.subplot(1,3,3)
plt.scatter(sim_time, acel)
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('Time [secs]')
plt.ylabel('Acceleration [ms2]')

plt.show()
```

Con el código anterior obtengo la siguiente gráfica:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve no alcanza los 1000m y se estabiliza, si no que continua creciendo.

Creo que el error puede ser porque estoy admitiendo una velocidad negativa, que no tendría mucho sentido, pero si defino que cuando la velocidad sea menor que 0, la velocidad tome el valor 0, tendría error nan.

Muchísimas gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Qué resultado retorna? El código que publicas está incompleto. Necesitamos algo que sea copiar y pegar en la IDE para poder ejecutarlo.

Comment: Buenas!  Perdón! Ahora está completo! Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

No sabes cuando parar.

Agrega este `if` luego de calcular `e_t1`.

```
e_t1 = error(s_setpoint, s_0)
if abs(e_t1) < 0.001:
    break
```

La idea es parar cuando estés a una distancia razonable del objetivo.

Eso produce:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Eso funcionaría, sí, pero... Rompe la dinámica del controlador. La idea es que el controlador debe seguir operando constantemente durante todo el tiempo. Imponiendo eso, cuando se alcanza ese nivel el controlador deja de funcionar y este tipo de sistemas funcionan y evaluan todo el tiempo manteniendo la respuesta, luego romper el bucle carece de sentido en este caso...

Comment: @JoseMariaHerrera. Entiendo tu punto. Trate de lograr lo que pides, pero abandone. Creo que tu modelo está mal planteado (puede que lo haya entendido mal: 1) Calculo de la velocidad no incluye la fricciòn. Con aceleraciòn cero, la velocidad serìa constante. 2) Calculo del factor integral debe hacerse sobre el delta de posición, no sobre el delta de velocidad. 3) No tiene sentido calcular el delta de velocidad, tu setpoint es distancia, no velocidad. 4) Tus factores integral y derivativo estàn en cero, lo que me dice que aùn te falta enfrentar el manejo de la inercia, entre otros.

Comment: @JoseMariaHerrera. Continuaciòn. Sin embargo, creo que es un problema interesante. Te propongo que lo mejores y cuando tengas incorporados fricciòn y los factores integral y derivativos, lo vuelvas a plantear. Mi primer proyecto Arduino fue construir un sous-vide (baño marìa a temperatura constante) controlado con un algoritmo PID. Logre una precisiòn de +/- 0.1ªC y lo uso frecuentemente en mi cocina (pasteurizar huevos, cocinar carnes y otras cosas que requieran temp. precisas).

Comment: El tema es que es una primera aproximación a un movimiento rectilíneo uniformemente acelerado, sin ningún tipo de pérdidas (ni fricción, ni aerodinámica...) . En cuanto a que los términos integral y derivativo no funcionen es porque aún solo con control proporcional aparece error, luego lo primero sería solucionar el error en control proporcional y después pasar al PID completo.

Comment: Continuación. El calcular el setoint de velocidad viene regido por el diagrama de bloques que presenté en la Figura. En un vehículo, lo único sobre lo que tienes control es sobre la aceleración (que vendrá dada por el par motor, y que aquí ha sido asemejado a la aceleración del movimiento) luego el PID actuará sobre la aceleración, y desarrollando el diagrama de bloques, el factor integral aparece sobre la velocidad. Por ello, el setpoint de posición va relacionado con el parámetro velocidad.